Why does Power Query of a table of URLs show ''Null" when the URLs contain data?
I have a list of URLs e.g.
...net/family_tree/100.html
...net/family_tree/105.html
...net/family_tree/110.html
etc.
Power Query can get data from the first URL ...net/family_tree/100.html but returns "null" for the others. How can I get Power Query to return data from all the URLs in the table?
I did a Power Query for one URL and it returned data. I then edited the query to use URLs from a table of URLs. It returned data from the first URL but, came back with "null" for the other URLs.
This is the code that works for the query on the one URL i.e.
"file:///C:/Viking%20Family%20Htmls/591.html"  :-
    let
    Source = File.Contents("file:///C:/Viking%20Family%20Htmls/591.html"),
    #"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(Source, {{"Column1", "BODY > TABLE:nth-child(1) > * > TR > :nth-child(1)"}}, [RowSelector="BODY > TABLE:nth-child(1) > * > TR"]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Extracted Table From Html",{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Column1] = "f a m i l y#(lf)#(lf)Children with:Gauthild Algautsdotter#(lf)Children:Olav Tretelgja#(lf)#(lf)Ingjald Anundsson#(lf)#(lf)Born: 690"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"

####
This is the code that works on the 1st URL of a table but returns "null" on the other URLs in the table :-
###
let Getdata=(URL) =>

let
    Source = File.Contents(URL),
    #"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(Source, {{"Column1", "BODY > TABLE:nth-child(1) > * > TR > :nth-child(1)"}}, [RowSelector="BODY > TABLE:nth-child(1) > * > TR"]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Extracted Table From Html",{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Column1] = "f a m i l y#(lf)#(lf)Children with:Gauthild Algautsdotter#(lf)Children:Olav Tretelgja#(lf)#(lf)Ingjald Anundsson#(lf)#(lf)Born: 690"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"

in Getdata

####
When I do "Add Custom Column" on the results from the above query it produces a table that has data for
file:///C:/Viking%20Family%20Htmls/591.html
but has "null" for
file:///C:/Viking%20Family%20Htmls/592.html
file:///C:/Viking%20Family%20Htmls/587.html 
etc.

####
When I run the above code it produces a query called "Vikings". Below is the code I see when I click on "Advanced Editor" :-
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Vikings"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Vikings List", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each fxVikings([Vikings List])),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Column1"}, {"Column1"})
in
    #"Expanded Custom"

###
Please let me know if you want images from the single and the table queries. If you do, do can I just copy the image into this question?
Thanks for your interest so far, hopefully you can help.

I think the description of your problem is inaccurate. Because what you described is just impossible! Better paste your code here too.

How do I send you a copy of the Excel spreadsheet with the code, and images from my Excel query?

In powerquery go to home .., advanced editor ... copy that code and edit your question above to  share it. Also provide the code from when it worked for a single item

I'm going to guess that your single query code would not work on the second hardcoded url because your second row or your filter row is too specific to the first url

Horseyride,Thanks for for getting back to me. Any ideas on how I should construct the query so that it will work?

Could you try to remove Filtered Rows in GetData and see whether it helps:
let Getdata=(URL) =>

let
    Source = File.Contents(URL),
    #"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(Source, {{"Column1", "BODY > TABLE:nth-child(1) > * > TR > :nth-child(1)"}}, [RowSelector="BODY > TABLE:nth-child(1) > * > TR"]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Extracted Table From Html",{{"Column1", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"

in Getdata

The filter could be too restrictive; if it turns out to be the cause, you could add filter conditions incrementally to get what you want.
I was able to load content from multiple file URLs in similar manner, but I didn't filter any rows.
